# Writing covariance matrix as orthogonal model

Tags: r, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix

From the book *Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis* by Johnson and Wichern, the following covariance matrix is written as an orthogonal model.
$$\bf \Sigma  = L{L^\top} + \mathbf \Psi $$

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{19}&{30}&2&{12}\\{30}&{57}&5&{23}\\2&5&{38}&{47}\\{12}&{23}&{47}&{68}\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}4\\7\\{ - 1}\\1\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}1\\2\\6\\8\end{array}} \right]  \left[ \begin{array}{l}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}4&7&{ - 1}&1\end{array}\\\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}1&2&6&8\end{array}\end{array} \right] + \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}2&0&0&0\\0&4&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&3\end{array}} \right] $$

Is there anyway, that we can get this result in R?

Comment: https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/soga/Geodata-analysis/factor-analysis/A-simple-example-of-FA/index.html

Comment: One caveat is $\mathbf \Sigma$ need not be factored in the desired way.

Comment: I guess you can make this an answer @Zhanxiong.

Comment: To OP, please don't forget to capitalise author's surname.

Comment: You know this is factor analysis already, and the question basically boils down basically to "can one perform FA in R?"

Comment: @User1865345 - questions and answers  on CV is essentially a wiki - you can edit any question and answer to improve it, you don't need to ask OK to do it. (I formatted the book title).

Comment: Indeed @JeremyMiles. Agree with you. I added the caps and left the comment for OP to keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One [link](https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/soga/Geodata-analysis/factor-analysis/A-simple-example-of-FA/index.html) that answers your question has been provided in the comment.

Another reference that is probably helpful is Section 11.3 of [Modern Applied Statistics with S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387954570), Fourth Edition, by W.N. Venables and B.D. Ripley. This textbook is a must-have (in my opinion) if you want to explore applied statistics with R software (or its commercial version S-plus).